# sylius version upgrade 0.10 to 0.11 is not working

Tags: symfony, sylius

while i am upgrading sylius standard version from 0.10 to 0.11, i have got an error.

```
  [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]  
   The child node "classes" at path "sylius_api" must be configured.
```

i had just updated this two requires in composer.json

```
   "sylius/sylius":                        "0.11.*@dev",
   "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "@dev"
```

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SyliusApiBundle is new in version 0.11.

You'll need to edit your [`app/config/sylius.yml`](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/2b15b72b436c3ea7d97c49e1787b5480e8fef145/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/sylius.yml#L37) file and add:

```
sylius_api:
    classes:
        api_user:
            model: %sylius.model.user.class%
```

However, I suspect you'll encounter more breaking changes as a result of the upgrade.